# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Table 'exchange_development.documents' doesn't exist: SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM `documents`

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm getting the following error: https://gist.github.com/glaksmono/859e495d61bfb4c66e1bdb24dbdf5719

And here's what I have in my databases:

```
mysql> mysql> SHOW DATABASES;
+----------------------+
| Database             |
+----------------------+
| information_schema   |
| exchange_development |
| exchange_production  |
| exchange_test        |
| mysql                |
| performance_schema   |
| sys                  |
+----------------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> USE exchange_development;
Database changed
mysql> SHOW TABLES;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

I've tried executing `bundle exec rake db:schema:load` prior, and been searching over the web on this but none has worked so far. Thoughts?

Comment: I am not sure about your issue but something is trying to use documents table before/while the application initialization. It may be in initializers or in your exception it is saying routes line number 1, can you please paste the routes file and document model.

Comment: I assume you are using class Document somewhere in the `environment.rb`, `routes.rb` or migrations.
So when you run migrations rails tries to initialize the class and ActiveRecord tries to connect to the proper table.
Please add `routes.rb`, `environment.rb` and migrations code

Comment: you don't have any tables in your db. How did you generate the `Document` model? You need `rake db:migrate`, probably.